# Factorio: Logistic Storage Overall View

Tags: factorio

I am starting to get hang of using logistic network. However I ran into a slight problem.

I am completely unable to view my entire logistic network's stock list. Just the top few row at the most. I have far more item that aren't visible on the right side.

[image: Logistic Storage Chest view]

For example if I want to see how many "electric circuits" I have. It is out of screen space.

I used an empty logistic storage chest on purpose because if there was item in there then that would push the rest of storage even more off screen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By pressing the L key ([default keybindings](https://wiki.factorio.com/Keyboard_bindings)) a menu opens up showing far more detail about the logistics networks you have.

This includes a (searchable) list of items in the network.

Comment: I'd add a screenshot but I'm at work right now :(

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Much thank.